# Google Cloud SQL-Unable to connect to MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect to my MySQL database hosted on Google Cloud Platform using Java and HikariConfig API (as shown in tutorial by Google). I am building my code in Eclipse but despite doing everything I could think of, my connection is not working. I am able to connect to same database using Mysql workbench (using public api) and using localhost (in place of Google App Engine). I think I'm missing a jar file in my project. I am adding the code and screenshots of my jar library.

the error I'm getting is below:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method com/google/cloud/sql/mysql/SocketFactory.connect(Ljava/lang/String;ILcom/mysql/cj/conf/PropertySet;I)Ljava/io/Closeable; is abstract
at com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory.connect (SocketFactory.java)
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect (NativeSocketConnection.java:65)
at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect (NativeSession.java:152)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly (ConnectionImpl.java:955)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO (ConnectionImpl.java:825)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init> (ConnectionImpl.java:455)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance (ConnectionImpl.java:240)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect (NonRegisteringDriver.java:199)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection (DriverDataSource.java:117)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection (DriverDataSource.java:123)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection (PoolBase.java:365)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry (PoolBase.java:194)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry (HikariPool.java:460)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast (HikariPool.java:534)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init> (HikariPool.java:115)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init> (HikariDataSource.java:81)
at com.x.d3sols.web.ConnectionPoolContextListener.createConnectionPool (ConnectionPoolContextListener.java:51)
at com.x.d3sols.web.ConnectionPoolContextListener.contextInitialized (ConnectionPoolContextListener.java:71)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized (ContextHandler.java:843)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized (ServletContextHandler.java:533)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext (ContextHandler.java:816)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext (ServletContextHandler.java:345)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp (WebAppContext.java:1406)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppEngineWebAppContext.startWebapp (AppEngineWebAppContext.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext (WebAppContext.java:1368)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart (ContextHandler.java:778)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart (ServletContextHandler.java:262)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart (WebAppContext.java:522)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppEngineWebAppContext.doStart (AppEngineWebAppContext.java:120)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler (AppVersionHandlerMap.java:240)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler (AppVersionHandlerMap.java:178)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest (JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:120)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest (JavaRuntime.java:722)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest (JavaRuntime.java:685)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run (JavaRuntime.java:655)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$NullSandboxRequestRunnable.run (JavaRuntime.java:847)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run (ThreadGroupPool.java:270)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
```

This is pretty critical for me, any help will be hugely appreciated. Thanks :)

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ConnectionPoolContextListener
 */
@WebListener("Creates a connection pool that is stored in the Servlet's context for later use.")
public class ConnectionPoolContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    // Saving credentials in environment variables is convenient, but not secure - consider a more
    // secure solution such as https://cloud.google.com/kms/ to help keep secrets safe.
    private static final String DB_USER = "<user>";
    private static final String DB_PASS = "<password>";
    private static final String CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME = "<Connection_Name>";
    private static final String DB_NAME = "<DB_Name>";

      private DataSource createConnectionPool() {
            // [START cloud_sql_mysql_servlet_create]
            // The configuration object specifies behaviors for the connection pool.
            HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();

            //For Localhost - IT WORKS
            /*String url = "jdbc:mysql://<IP_Address>/<DB_NAME>";
            config.setJdbcUrl(url);
            config.setUsername(DB_USER); 
            config.setPassword(DB_PASS);
            config.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            config.addDataSourceProperty("useSSL", "false");*/

            //For APP ENGINE - IT DOESNT WORKS
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://google/<DB_NAME>";
            config.setJdbcUrl(url);
            config.setUsername(DB_USER);
            config.setPassword(DB_PASS);
            config.addDataSourceProperty("socketFactory", "com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory");
            config.addDataSourceProperty("cloudSqlInstance", CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME);
            config.addDataSourceProperty("useSSL", "false");
            config.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            config.setMaximumPoolSize(5);
            config.setMinimumIdle(5);
            config.setConnectionTimeout(60000); 
            config.setIdleTimeout(600000); 
            config.setMaxLifetime(1800000); // 30 minutes
            DataSource pool = new HikariDataSource(config);
            return pool;
          }


      @Override
      public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // This function is called when the Servlet is destroyed.
        HikariDataSource pool = (HikariDataSource) event.getServletContext().getAttribute("my-pool");
        if (pool != null) {
          pool.close();
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // This function is called when the application starts and will safely create a connection pool
        // that can be used to connect to.
        DataSource pool = (DataSource) event.getServletContext().getAttribute("my-pool");
        if (pool == null) {
          pool = createConnectionPool();
          event.getServletContext().setAttribute("my-pool", pool);
        }
      }
}
```

[Here is the screenshot of my folder where I've added missing libraries that I could think of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RXtU.png)

Comment: Please provide the full exception stacktrace you get.

Comment: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/cloud/sql/mysql/SslSocketFactory
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.throwPoolInitializationException (HikariPool.java:548)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast (HikariPool.java:540)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init> (HikariPool.java:113)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.

Comment: Here us the stack trace @MarkRotteveel

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Don't put things like this in comments. But in any case, the error indicates that you probably don't have `com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory` on the classpath

Comment: sorry things like what?

Comment: the stacktrace, the more information you provide about the issue you are facing is better.

Comment: You shouldn't put updates to your question in the comments. Especially not stacktraces. Please [edit] your question and put the full stacktrace in your question (the stacktrace in the comment doesn't seem to be complete).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.. I've updated as you requested with latest error stacktrace

Answer (score 2):

once I had the same issue (I know how painful it is) and as much as I would I dont have to much experience with java but this is what I can tell you about how I connect cloud-sql with app-engine

Be aware of this two things:

If you want to connect **cloud-sql** with **app-engine** the connection must be via `socket` otherwise it doesn't connect and if you want to connect from **localhost** to **cloud-sql** it should be via `tcp`. In the last case your public ip needs to be added to *authorized networks* in `connections` section.

So as far as I can see what you are doing is ok but you can try to format the url as is suggested in the docs:

```
HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
config.setJdbcUrl(String.format("jdbc:mysql:///%s", DB_NAME));
```

and one last thing you need to be sure that the format of `CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME` is as follows:

```
CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME = 'project-id:region:instance-id'

// You can get this information from the overview page in google cloud console - sql.
```

For more information you can review this two links [Google docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine) and [Java example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/cloud-sql/mysql/servlet)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Arnold..really appreciate your help..let me give your suggestions a try and see if it helps

Comment: Now the new error is RuntimeException: Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql:///<DB_Name>

Comment: Now maybe it is trying to connect but the driver is missing.

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to solve it with help from the comments. Apparently there was a string missing in appengine-web.xml file which I added and it got fixed. I also replaced some jar files in my classpath.

The string to be added in appengine-web.xml is:

```
<use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>
```

And your libraries will look like below:
[image: Libs]

Please be conscious of the version of all the libs that you use, I'm using v8. All libraries except Gson are required for this.

Comment: Hi Mohit Sharma, good work finding the solution! Can you accept your own answer? It will make it more visible and help someone with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks!